Checking values row per row to assign proper work center to product
I am tasked with matching the products from a table to the Work Center they are supposed to be sent to. To do this, I have 2 tables: one contains the details about what product goes to what Work Center, and one containing the informations about the product to be made.
The product names are usually like this str (group) int( size) and may or may not be followed by other strings (the motor to make), or a '/T' which doesn't affect the work center associated
The first table about the products and work centers:



Mdt
Div.
Type_group
Type_size
target_time
Workcenter
Opratio
Da_rivedere




400
4000
R*
37*
11.000
CELL21
0312



400
4000
S*
37*
11.000
CELL21
0312



400
4000
SA*
37*
11.000
CELL21
0312



400
4000
K*
19*
40.000
CELL23
0320
X


400
4000
K*
29*
40.000
CELL23
0320
X


400
4000
F*
37*
18.500
CELL24
0313



400
4000
F*
47*
18.500
CELL24
0313



400
4000
FA*
37*
18.500
CELL24
0313



400
4000
FA*
47*
18.500
CELL24
0313



400
4000
K*
37*
26.000
CELL24
0313



400
4000
K*
47*
27.000
CELL24
0313



400
4000
KA*
37*
26.000
CELL24
0313



400
4000
KA*
47*
27.000
CELL24
0313




Here, this shows that, for example:
In the first row, if product name starts with R and which has any other character after that, and if it has a size of 37 and anything else attached to it, should go to the Work Center -> CELL21
Now, take a look at the orders table instead:



Index
SFC
Prodotto




0
841317030100.00.0001
R37 DRN90L2


1
841342450100.00.0001
SA37 DRN93M3


2
841345010100.00.0001
R37 AQH80/1


3
841345010200.00.0001
KAZ47 DRN132S4/BE5HR/TF


4
841345010100.00.0002
FA47 AQH80/1



It shows that, the first product is called:
R37 DRN90L2
This is exactly the case I just described above, it's an R , and size is 37 both of which conditions match the Work Center to be CELL21.
Therefore, the final dataset should be as follows (these are all examples you can verify with the excerpt of table I sent above):



Index
SFC
Prodotto
WorkCenter




0
841317030100.00.0001
R37 DRN90L2
CELL21


1
841342450100.00.0001
SA37 DRN93M3
CELL21


2
841345010100.00.0001
R37 AQH80/1
CELL21


3
841345010200.00.0001
KAZ47 DRN132S4/BE5HR/TF
CELL24


4
841345010100.00.0002
FA47 AQH80/1
CELL24



Now, what I am trying to do, is to match through the use of regex each of the rows for the dataset containing the details of the orders, and when I obtain a group to cross-check it with the table of the products and work centers to return the work centers into which it should go:
import pandas as pd
import re

df_products = pd.read_excel('orders_table.xlsx')
df_rules = pd.read_excel('products_work_centers.xlsx')

def match_workcenter(prodotto, df_rules):
    # Extract group and size from the product code using regex
    match = re.match(r"([A-Z]+)(\d+)", prodotto)
    if match:
        group, size = match.groups()
        size = size + '*'  
        for _, row in df_rules.iterrows():
            if group == row['Type_group'].replace('*', '') and size == row['Type_size']:
                return row['Workcenter']
    return None

df_products['New_Workcenter'] = df_products['Prodotto'].apply(lambda x: match_workcenter(x, df_rules))

df_products

But the result is not satisfactory, as for some of these cells it works and some others it doesn't:



Index
SFC
Prodotto
WorkCenter




0
841317030100.00.0001
R37 DRN90L2
CELL21


1
841342450100.00.0001
WAF20 DRN63M4/BE03
None


2
841345010100.00.0001
WA20 DRN63M4
None


3
841345010200.00.0001
WA20 DRN63M4
None


4
841345010100.00.0002
KAZ67 DRN132S4/BE5HR/TF
None



Can I get some advice into how to modify this to work?

Assuming there is only one Workcenter per Type_group and Type_size, and your dataframes are named df_workcenters and df_orders, you can use this approach:
type_map = {
    k: f"{v1}{v2}"
    for k in df_orders["Prodotto"]
    for v1, v2 in zip(df_workcenters["Type_group"], df_workcenters["Type_size"])
    if re.search(rf'^{re.sub(r"\*", ".", v1)}', k)
    and re.search(rf'{re.sub(r"\*", ".", v2)}', k)
}

df_orders["Type_group_size"] = df_orders["Prodotto"].map(type_map)
df_workcenters["Type_group_size"] = (
    df_workcenters["Type_group"] + df_workcenters["Type_size"]
)

df_orders = df_orders.merge(
    df_workcenters[["Type_group_size", "Workcenter"]].drop_duplicates(),
    on="Type_group_size",
    how="left",
)

   Index                   SFC                 Prodotto Type_group_size Workcenter
0      0  841317030100.00.0001              R37 DRN90L2           R*37*     CELL21
1      1  841342450100.00.0001             SA37 DRN93M3          SA*37*     CELL21
2      2  841345010100.00.0001              R37 AQH80/1           R*37*     CELL21
3      3  841345010200.00.0001  KAZ47 DRN132S4/BE5HR/TF          KA*47*     CELL24
4      4  841345010100.00.0002             FA47 AQH80/1          FA*47*     CELL24


Thank you! Exactly what I couldn't put into code from words :D
